# In Angular, using array.map() in declaring routes causes "ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-cli-v7, angular7-router

I'm getting an error when building the project.

> ng build --prod

The following Is the error showing on the console.

```
Date: 2019-05-06T07:11:31.860Z
Hash: 86bc6833bfe9e981c890
Time: 12080ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} es2015-polyfills.c5dd28b362270c767b34.js (es2015-polyfills) 56.4 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {2} main.fa4681da67b0e16d34dc.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.41559ea504b9f00b6dea.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]

**ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined**
```

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- node v10.15.3
- npm 6.4.1
- @angular/cli 7.3.8

**Repro steps**

1) create new angular app with routing

1.1) ng new MyApp

1.2.) when prompted to use routing, say yes and accept the other defaults

2) ng g component Home

3) ng g component Settings

4) And modify the app-routing.module.ts with following.

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: "settings",
        component: SettingsComponent
      }
    ];

    const routes2 = routes.map( e => ({ path: e.path, component: e.component}) );

    const routes3 = [];
    routes.forEach( e => ( routes3.push({ path: e.path, component: e.component})) );

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        // RouterModule.forRoot(routes2), // **this doesn't work**
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes3) // but this one works just fine
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

5) ng build --prod

Error should appear in the console

**The question**

Looking at step 4, my question really is why is that the following works?

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes3)
```

whereas the following doesn't work?

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes2)
```

Note that `routes`, `routes2`, and `routes3` are all the same, at least equivalent, looking at their structure. They are all just arrays of objects with the same attributes. Not sure what I'm missing here.

UPDATE:

The following surprisingly doesn't work too.

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot( routes3.concat([]) );
```

But the following works.

```js
    RouterModule.forRoot( routes3 );
```

This is really strange. It must be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: First you say `RouterModule.forRoot(routes3)` doesn't work and at the end you say it works. Typo in the number?

Comment: @jowey, thanks for spotting that! Updated the question. Yes, it is typo. `routes3` works, `routes2` doesn't. `routes3.concat([])` doesn't work too despite being just the same as `routes3`.

Comment: paths should not start with slash, at least that is what router usually tells me. Might be the complier trips when you do it this way.

Comment: That's a good question but here should be no surprises after reading the section in Angular docs about Ahead of time compilation https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler. Shortly, Angular static analyzer can't recognize your calls but does recognizes `const routes3 = [];` since it's a simple array. You can also write `let routes = []; routes2 = routes.map(...)` and it will also work but compiler won't recognize any routes with loadChildren property

Comment: @mchl18, thanks, that was a typo. Updated the question.

Comment: @yurzui, thanks for the reference. I'll check it out.

Comment: @yurzui thank you for pointing out the problem with loadChildren. After rethinking it seems quite obvious that this doesn't work (different usecase than in the question, but the case why I was interested in the overall problem of dynamic route generation).